# How To Get The Value Of An Environment Variable In Elixir On Windows?

Tags: environment-variables, elixir, configuration-files

Windows 10

Elixir 1.3.1

Per the advice in [this article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/05/how-to-config-environment-variables-with-elixir-and-exrm/), I've tried to modify my config files to use the "${ENV_VAR}" syntax. But then when I try to compile the code Elixir complains about the values of the configuration settings.  So I tried the syntax directly in iex and it doesn't seem to work.

```
iex(1)> "${PATH}"
"${PATH}"
iex(2)> System.get_env("PATH")
"C:\\Program Files\\erl8.0\\erts-8.0\\bin;C: . . ." (rest omitted for brevity's sake)
```

I'd really like to use the "${ENV_VAR}" notation because it'd be nice to not have to hand-edit the sys.config file.  Am I doing something wrong or is this just a Windows specific issue?

Here's part of my config file (even though, as I say, it seems I can reproduce the behavior in iex):

config :riismi, ecto_repos: [Riismi.Repo]

```
config :riismi, Riismi.Mailer,
    adapter: Bamboo.SMTPAdapter,
    server: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    username: "${RMI_MAIL_SERVERUSER}",
    password: "${RMI_MAIL_SERVERPWD}",
    tls: :if_available, # can be `:always` or `:never` or `:if_available`
    ssl: true, # can be `true`
    retries: 3
```

As I say, I realize this is likely to be a Windows issue--just wanted to insure that I'm not missing something otherwise.

Comment: 1. Why don't you just roll with `System.get_env("ENV_VAR_NAME_HERE")`?
2. The article you linked says that the "${NAME}" notation works `when we build an Exrm release` -  `Instead of using System.get_env in our configs, we must use "${ENV_VAR}". Then, we just need to run our release with RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS=true.`

Comment: I am trying to build with Exrm.